# How to track urls without sessions and encrypted url in google analytics in a decent way?

Tags: google-analytics

## General setting

I have a website, which uses regular and encrypted urls. Now I want to track the pageviews or all pages the same way.

I have regular URLs like this:

```
/library.dll?page=page12&arg1=0&arg2=some&session_id=7892734
```

and special pages like this:

```
/library.dll?page=specialpage&arg1=0&arg2=some&session_id=7892734&id=page13
```

aswell as **encrypted** URLs like this, which are also containing the session id:

```
/library.dll?page=encrypted&args=gYZEI7lnRAQLzVXdtdbcral8.cOoc6NDtMUGY2yep9wO3JM
```

So the interesting niformation is always the `page`, which is in this examples `page12`, `page13` and `page14` (where `page14` is also part of the encrypted string).

## Clarification

I can change the HTML and JS code only. I have no access to the Google Analytics interfaces at all. This will be administrated by multiple customers.
The GA code will be integrated within a template using a customer-specific code and their unique tracking id.

## Problem description

I need to track the `page` argument, because this is basically the interesting part of the url. When tracking other url parameters I cannot accumulate the pageviews for a certain page, because Google Analytics shows them as separate pages.

In addition I don't see any way to track the pageviews with encrypted URLs, because I cannot set a generic name for them unless there is a way to utilize the method `ga('send', 'pageview');`

## Solution idea

1. I read about overwriting the pageview attributes like this:
   `ga('send', 'pageview', '/my-overridden-page?id=1');`
   in the [article on page tracking @Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)
2. Utilizing [(event) triggers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) is in my opinion a pretty bad idea.

## The question itself

Is there any smarter way to track this information? Is extracting the page-information and overwriting the pageview attributes the best way to do this?
I just started using GA and have kind of no idea how to do this any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use filters (custom advanced filters) to rewrite the request url inside the google admin interface (admin->views->filters). This has the advantage that you do not need to change your site/application code.

However using filters will require multi-step-filters with heavy use of regular expressions, and you would have to test this in a "staging" view first (because a wrong filter will permanently mess up your data).

Passing a custom url to the pageview tracking is pretty straightforward and can be tested immediately via the real time view. In my opinion this is indeed the smartest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I won't be able to access the admin interface. This is part of an application which will be deployed and is out of my control. There will be several customers using this in their own GA dashboard. The only thing I can modify is the HTML / JS.

Comment: Like I said, you are on the right track anyway - passing an argument to trackpageview is certainly the way to go and will cause the least headache.